# Accidentally pulled down a bunch of git files, how do I remove them?

Tags: git

I was in the wrong folder, and I did `git init` followed by `git pull *repo*`, now my folder is cluttered with files I don't want. Is there a way to get rid of them all?

Comment: `git init` initializes an *empty* repository without any configured remote. Therefore a `git pull` will not fetch anything. - You did something else.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`, `git status`, and `git branch -vv`? (Please update your question.)

Comment: @michas Unless the directory in question was already a repository, in which case you get the message "Reinitialized existing Git repository in ....". Not sure what other effects it does/doesn't have, but any previously-defined remotes will still be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just did the init (assumes you are not on a windows OS):

```
dir=`pwd`
cd ..
rm -rf $dir
mkdir $dir
cd $dir
git init
```

Comment: But that will totally blow away whatever folder the user is currently in. It sounds to me like there might be other stuff in there he doesn't want to delete.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my issue.